# need help understanding a bash read command

Tags: bash

Below is read command I'm trying to understand:-

```
read -p $'\e[1;92m List of sites: \e[0m' records
```

-p flag prompts the user to enter a file name for a list of sites which it names records. Can someone help me with the the rest of the syntax between the quotes.
Thanks

Comment: https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x329.html.  These are escape sequences, that allow you to specify colors of text, and other things (ex. cursor movement).  FYI welcome to SO, you should take the [tour] and read [ask].  You are expected to research on your own before posting.

Comment: Those are ANSI escape sequences to control color, font styling and so on. Some text terminals (or terminal emulators) interpret these sequences as commands, rather than text to display verbatim,

Answer (score 0):

The second argument in your command - i.e. the parameter for the `-p` argument - that starts with `$'` and ends with `'`, is the text to be displayed to the user, prompting them to enter some text to be assigned to the `records` shell variable.

The content of that argument is some text interspersed with [ANSI control sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) that instruct the terminal to color the prompt green and then reset the color before the user starts typing.

Comment: Thanks for that - I've has a look at the ANSI control sequences link and it make more sense now.